# How to properly remove a dependency in a Maven project

Tags: maven, junit, testng, pom.xml, dependency-management

I have a Java Maven project where I have some dependencies defined in the pom.xml file. Recently I decided to move from Junit to TestNG so I deleted the Junit dependency from my pom.xml and added the TestNG one.

I was expecting to see the Junit jar library disappear from the Maven Dependencies folder as a part of the process but that didn't happen. I can still see the jar file in the dependencies folder and it is still being used by my test cases.

I can see TestNG jar is there as well but it's not being used. I can change it manually of course but that wasn't my intention.

Am I doing something wrong are there any additional steps that I missed that will allow me to remove the old dependency?

Comment: Are you talking about Maven in Eclipse? It's enough to remove the dependency from the pom.xml to remove it from the project. If it's still here, you made something else wrong. Have you added some jar manually?

Comment: @Bevor Yes, I am working with pom file through Eclipse. I didn't add anything manually. Everything through pom file.

Comment: Do you have the Maven integration for Eclipse plugin?

Comment: You must be aware that TestNG has a dependency to JUnit itself...which means JUnit will not disappear...

Comment: If you're using maven and Eclipse, you may need to 'update' the maven project. In Eclipse: Right mouse-click on project root -> `Maven` -> `Update Project ...`

Answer (score 0):

The following applies for the global `.m2` folder where maven dependencies can be downloaded and is common to your maven projects.

the .m2 folder will not clean by itself as those dependencies could be used in another project so its wrong assumption that replacing a dependency in a a `pom` file will automatically remove from your repo.

you can look at the [depedency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html) and run the following

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

or

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DreResolve=false
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how this dependency can be used for another project if a pom file is defined per project?

Comment: The `pom` file is defined per project but the `.m2` local repo is global on your system, so all dependencies will be downloaded there.